# Airflow replaces its name with 3 asterix

Tags: airflow

Airflow version: v2.4.2.

When rendering a template, Airflow replaces "airflow" occurrences with ***

(in my case it is a part of an URL)

The render looks like:
href='https://suffix***.example.com/dagrun/list/...'

instead of:
href='https://suffixairflow.example.com/dagrun/list/...'

Has anyone observed such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior with secrets masking. Most likely "airflow" is a password or some other secret for your environment (I suspect for the Postgres database). Instances of "airflow" will be masked accordingly.